# deleting rows having a particular date in the datetime column of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have to remove the rows having date "2019-10-07" in the first column date.

I have created a `date1` column that extracts the exact date from first column and then apply the code,

```
df2 = df2[df2['date1'] != '2019-10-07'].
```

I have to create this `date1` column because it was mentioned in the problem.
the link to the data frame is as follows:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vTKoaQ2rtpup5gPXjmQIavG5v4owNRvk/view?usp=sharing

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 df2=pd.read_csv('TCS.csv').sort_values(by='Date') 
 date1 = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%Y/%m/%d,%H:%M:%S', 
 errors='coerce') #few rows were having a diff date format
 date2 = pd.to_datetime(df2.loc[date1.isna(), 'Date'], format='%d-%m- 
 %Y,%H:%M:%S')
 df2['Date'] = date1.fillna(date2)                    
 df2['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format= '%Y/%m/%d').dt.date             
 df2['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format= '%Y/%m/%d').dt.time

 df2 = df2[df2['date1'] != '2019-10-07']
```

The code

```
df2 = df2[df2['date1'] == '2019-10-07']
```

is working when applying it seperately with the new dataframe. but not in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking for equality against a string even though your values are of type datetime.date. Try the following:

```
df2[df2['date1'] != pd.to_datetime('2019-10-07',format = '%Y-%m-%d').date()]
```

Comment: and what to write for if i want my dataframe to lie between 2 days, let say 2019-05-10 and 2019-06-12

Comment: Try something like this approach

interval = pd.Interval(pd.to_datetime('2019-10-04',format = '%Y-%m-%d').date(),pd.to_datetime('2019-10-07',format = '%Y-%m-%d').date(), closed = 'both')
df2[df2['date1'].apply(lambda x: x not in interval)]